# When i add contentscript using page-mod in firefox extension. The content script functions are executed thrice

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am unable to understand . Why my functions are executed thrice after addition in the firefox extension using "page-mod" .

This is my code :
[**main.js**]

```
var pageModOptions = {
    include: ["http://xyz.com/*"],
    attachTo: ["top", "frame", "existing"],
    contentScriptWhen: "end",
    onAttach: function(worker){
        worker.port.on("Done", function(elementContent) {
            console.log("emitted by tarun :" + elementContent);
            worker.port.emit("start", htmlfilePath);
        });
    },
};

pageModOptions.contentScriptFile = [data.url("js/main.js"),data.url("js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"),data.url("js/hello.js")];

//pageModOptions.contentScriptFile = data.url("js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js");
pageModOptions.contentStyleFile = data.url("js/main.css");
pageModOptions.contentScriptOptions = csOptions;
pageMod.PageMod(pageModOptions);
```

and in the contentscript [**hello.js**]

```
function test(){
    window.alert('testing phase 1');
}
test();
```

So this alert is called thrice . How to stop this behaviour .

Comment: Cannot reproduce based on the code you provided: worksforme, as in alerts once. Please provide a complete, reproducible example.

Comment: Can you share with me the code which you tested . I might get an idea ,where my code is going wrong . Also its a restartless extension .

Comment: I tested with your code, essentially, after dropping "unused" stuff that was still in there and `csOptions` which your code omits the definition of: https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/208869/latest/

Comment: Thanks alot .I will try the code and see where my code is going wrong .

Comment: @nmaier :  Can you help out on how to use google oauth2 inside firefox extension . With this same existing code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your content script will run exactly once for *each HTML document* loaded from `http://xyz.com/` - a separate instance of your content script will be injected into each of them. So seeing three alerts when this code runs can mean the following things:

- There are three browser tabs open with pages from `http://xyz.com/` loaded.
- There is only one browser tab but the page from `http://xyz.com/` loaded there includes two frames which are also loaded from `http://xyz.com/`.

Most likely, if you change `window.alert('testing phase 1')` into `window.alert(location.href)` your confusion will be cleared up.

Comment: Sorry, i have the same trouble, but your answer doesn't make it clear anyway: i do `console.log(location.href, window.self == window.top)` and when my Content Script gets executed, i see many many similar lines in the log, like this `http://example.com/ false`. Pls, help. Here's the question i created about this trouble - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484797/firefox-add-on-script-gets-executed-many-times

Comment: @lucifer63: As I said, most likely that page has multiple frames and your content script runs in each of them.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, there are some amount of frames, but how to prevent execution for frames if all of them has the same `location.href`?