# Firefox add-on script gets executed many times

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to create a simple add-on to edit an iframe at a certain page.

I read [the MDN add-on SDK tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK), found a [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Modifying_Web_Pages_Based_on_URL) which explains how to interact with a page, here is the *index.js*:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "http://www.kongregate.com/games/tfender/contract-wars",
  contentScriptFile: "./main.js"
});
```

Here is the *data/main.js*, the contentScriptFile:

```
window.__cw_fullscreen_started = false;

if (!__cw_fullscreen_started) {
    console.log('started!');
    __cw_fullscreen_started = true;
}
```

The last tutorial has an example showing how to use pageMod, here it is:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.org",
  contentScript: 'document.body.innerHTML = ' +
                 ' "<h1>Page matches ruleset</h1>";'
});
```

Everything's clear here: when i open some *.org* site, the script replaces the page content with *`<h1>Page matches ruleset</h1>`*. Seems the *document.body* links to a body of a document that belongs to a page the script is executed at.

But when i execute `jpm run` and visit *http://www.kongregate.com/games/tfender/contract-wars*, the page at which the *main.js* script should be executed, i see that *'started!'* has been logged many times.

I look through all the tutorials at MDN again again, but i have no idea why does it happen.

So the question: why the script gets executed so many times?

PS: in the answer to [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569298/when-i-add-contentscript-using-page-mod-in-firefox-extension-the-content-script) a guy said that "content script will run exactly once for each HTML document loaded from example.com", and said that logging location.href will clear up the confusion, but for me `console.log(location.href, window.self == window.top)` logs out  "www.example.com false" many times, so the confusion is not cleared up.